# Testing for statistical correlation using textual data

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, time-series, probability

I have sub-reddit data that shows total monthly mentions of collective action amongst the unemployed individuals using the sub-reddit of interest, and another variable that shows whether the month falls before or after a specific treatment was introduced (i.e. the treatment refers to an announcement of a UI benefit extension in a specific state).

Descriptively, it seems that the policy announcement did indeed have an effect on collective action mentions where they decline notably in the 4-6 months post-announcement.
However, I am interested in testing this statistically and I am not sure what is the suitable statistical test here. Specifically, if I am interested in saying that the policy announcement had a statistically significant impact on collective action mentions, what would be the correct statistical test to apply here?

Here is a data example:

```
dput(df[1:13,])
```

output:

```
structure(list(collective_action = structure(c(treatment_details = c("pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", 
    "pre", "pre", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post"
    ), month_year = structure(c(2011.41666666667, 2011.5, 2011.75, 
    2011.83333333333, 2011.91666666667, 2012, 2012.08333333333, 
    2012.16666666667, 2012.25, 2012.33333333333, 2012.41666666667, 
    2012.5, 2012.58333333333), class = "yearmon"), n = c(22L, 
    17L, 55L, 15L, 207L, 195L, 265L, 182L, 203L, 121L, 178L, 
    43L, 117L), collective_action_percentage = c(0.0141752577319588, 
    0.0109536082474227, 0.0354381443298969, 0.00966494845360825, 
    0.133376288659794, 0.125644329896907, 0.170747422680412, 
    0.0759282436378807, 0.0846891948268669, 0.050479766374635, 
    0.0742594910304547, 0.017939090529829, 0.048811013767209), 
    treatment_details = c("post", "pre"), .rows = structure(list(
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an autoregressive model with a binary covariate indicating pre or post announcement. A simple AR(1) model can be written as follows:

$$y_{t} = \alpha + \beta_{1}y_{t-1} + \beta_{2}X_{t} + \epsilon$$

Fitting this model using R or Python is very easy and $\beta_{2}$ is the coefficient you are interested in, which tells you how $X$ (the binary variable indicating pre or post announcement) affects your response variable.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the assumptions required of simple statistical tests would fail for your premise.

The most simple examples (a 2-group binomial test as in prop.test or fisher
s exact test fisher.test in R) require the number of trials (total posts to the subreddit) to be randomly distributed separate from your dividing concepts (in this case calendar time and the policy decision) which are, I am assuming, unreasonable.

I would say that in general, statisticians are moving away from the concept of a p-value or threshold-based "decision" for this type of question, and this question is inherently better suited to be displayed and discussed descriptively using multiple estimators that consider the inherently longitudinal relationship of your data, such as fitting an ARIMA model and discussing the % change by month before and after the policy decision. Observational count data where people can both contribute many times and will leave and enter the population based on your covariates of interest violate the assumptions of most distribution-based hypothesis tests.